# getting issue in update query in sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am new in sails js and getting some issue my update query show updated successfully but it does not update the record in mongodb collection. I don't where i am doing silly mistake.

Here is controller function

```
edit: function(req, res){
    var uid = req.params.id;
    console.log("Request body----------" +uid);

    console.log(req.body.heading);
    console.log(req.body.message);
    Dashboard.update(
    { _id : uid },
    {title : "req.body.heading" , description : "req.body.message" }).exec(function(err, doc){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error while update"+err);
    }else{
        console.log("Successfuly Updated");
        res.redirect('dashboard/index');
    }
    });     
}
```

This is model file:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    title:{
         type:'string',
         //required:true,
         columnName:'title'
    },
    description: {
         type:'text',
         columnName:'description'
    },
    posted_by: {
        type: 'integer',
        columnName: 'posted_by'
    }

  }
```

Console message shows this

```
Successfully Updated
```

Any one help will be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you check if the document with the given `uid` exists in the first place? Also, `req.body.heading` and `req.body.message` shouldn't be quoted if you're referring to their values. Trying printing the `doc` in the callback to see if anything is being updated at all.

Comment: if we print doc , then its show this message in console
<br>
[]
Successfuly Updated

Comment: That just means no documents are being updated. Verify that the document with the provided id exists.

Comment: no, i checked the id it exist in db

Comment: Alright, can you try using `id` instead of `_id`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `id` istead of `_id` like

```
Dashboard.update(
  { id : uid },
  {title : "req.body.heading" , description : "req.body.message" }
)
```

It's `Waterline` conventions.